# Rails Simple_Form Add Years to Date Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm my Rails app, one of the fields for my `User` model is Date of Birth (`dob`).  The problem I'm having with Simple_Form is that the default dropdown only goes back until 2010 and I need it to go back much further.

Is there a way I can show additional years?

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :dob, order: [:month, :day, :year]
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the `start_year` and `end_year`:

```
= f.input :dob,
  start_year: Time.now.year - 100,
  end_year: Time.now.year - 18,
  order: %i(day month year)
```

[Checkout docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/frames) for more info on options.